# keyboard switch button shortcut with js

Tags: javascript, keyboard, shortcut

I want to create a keyboard shortcut that goes to one function, and when you press that key again, it returns to the original function.

For example I am using a paint tool, but I want to switch to an eraser by pressing something like tab, then when I'm done I switch back to the paint tool by pressing tab again.

I've done keyboard shortcuts before, but I've never done one that returns to the previous function...

Sorry if this is not clear, I'm not sure where to begin. Even if someone could guide me to a link that I can study I would really appreciate it.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/

Comment: This is just a keycode list, but thanks anyway

Comment: see down in website you can try with your keyboard and get the keycode

Comment: Yes I understand but it's not what I'm asking... I don't think I'm explaining my question well, I apologise.

Comment: ok, and sorry for the wrong guidence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var currentTool = 'brush';
var prevTool = '';

$('.paintToggle').keypress(function (e) { 
  var key = e.which; 
  switch (key) {
    case 6:
      if(currentTool !== 'eraser') {
        prevTool = currentTool;
        currentTool = 'eraser'; 
      } else {
        currentTool = prevTool;
      }
      break;
  }
  paint.select_tool(currentTool);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped my problem!!

Answer (score 0):

Use the below snipset.
Here, you should introduce yourClass name. Then action should be invoked for your key pressing.

```js
$('.yourClass').keypress(function (e) {
        var key = e.which;
        if(key == 13)  // the enter key code
        {
           //to do your action
        }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, so if I want it to return to the first brush by pressing 6 again, it will return to the first tool? Basically I want it to toggle between brush and eraser...

$('.paintToggle').keypress(function (e) {
        var key = e.which;
        if(key == 6) 
        {
           paint.select_tool('eraser');
        }else if(key == 6){
         paint.select_tool('brush');
        }
});

Comment: Yes, you should be able to do that